# just open the modal with two clicks in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar to create my calendar as shown in the code below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    initialViews = 'dayGridMonth';
}else{
    initialViews = 'dayGridMonth';
}

var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calmanut');

  var today = moment().day();

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {

    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth'
    },
    locale: "pt-br",
    buttonText:{
      today:    'Hoje',
      month:    'Mês',
    },

    navLinks: true,
      firstDay: today,
      initialView: initialViews,
      editable: true,
      selectable: true, 
      unselectAuto:true,
      eventOverlap: true,
      slotDuration: '00:30',
      allDaySlot : false,
      eventStartEditable: true,
      eventDurationEditable:false,
      longPressDelay: 0,
      nowIndicator: "true",
      expandRows: true,
      slotMinTime: '09:00',
      slotMaxTime: '18:00',
      contentHeight: 'auto',
      businessHours: {

        daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 
    
      },
      eventDidMount: function (info) {
        $(info.el).popover({
            title: info.event.title,
            placement: 'top',
            trigger: 'hover', 
            content: 'Período: ' + info.event.groupId,
            container: 'body'
        });
      },
      
      events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2023-11-17'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2023-11-17',
        end: '2023-09-10',
        color: 'purple' // override!
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2023-11-17T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        groupId: '999',
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2023-11-17T16:00:00'
      }
    ],
     eventClick:  function(info) {
        
        var eventObj = info.event; 
        tarperiod = eventObj.extendedProps.Tarefa;

        $('#ModalAddmanut1').modal("show");
        $('#ModalAddmanut1 #sidtaref').val(eventObj.extendedProps.Id);
        $('#ModalAddmanut1 #titletar1').val(eventObj.extendedProps.Tarefa);  
        $('#ModalAddmanut1 #cortaref1').val(eventObj.extendedProps.cor);
      },
    
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.9.0/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id='calmanut'></div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="ModalAddmanut1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">ELIMINAR/ALTERAR PLANIFICAÇÃO DE TAREFAS</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close atualvisita1" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" class="row g-3 instper1">
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="sidtaref" name="sidtaref">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-8">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="titletar1"> <strong>Tarefa</strong> </label>
                                    <select class="js-states form-control" name="titletar1" id="titletar1">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option>Teste</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cortaref1"> <strong>Cor</strong> </label>
                                    <select class="js-states form-control" name="cortaref1" id="cortaref1">
                                        <option value=""></option>                            
                                        <option style="color:#000;" value="#F00">&#9724; Vermelho</option>
                                        <option style="color:#000;" value="#FFF">&#9724; Branco</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>
                
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger valtareff1" id="save-event">Eliminar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary valtareff" id="save-event">Alterar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If used on the computer it works well. The problem is when I use it on a cell phone. I'm gonna explain:

On the computer, to see the eventDidMount, just hover the mouse over the event and open the tooltip. On the phone, to see the eventDidMount I have to click on the event and when I click, it opens the tooltip and the modal for editing.

The edit modal should only open with two clicks. Can you help me resolve the problem?

Comment: I have never used fullcalendar but from looking at your code, it seems the event trigger for the popover is set to "hover". You probably need a way to set the trigger to "click", "tap" or "double tap" depending on what the api offers.

Comment: @Aaron I don't know how to do it, I'm looking in the documentation and I can't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to be clear, I have no idea what full calendar is, I am only taking a rough stab by looking at your code. The code you posted already has a line for feature detection

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  initialViews = "dayGridMonth";
} else {
  initialViews = "dayGridMonth";
}
```

You can possibly use that to do something like this:

```
eventDidMount: function (info) {
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $(info.el).popover({
      title: info.event.title,
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'click', 
      content: 'Período: ' + info.event.groupId,
      container: 'body'
  });
  } else {
    $(info.el).popover({
      title: info.event.title,
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'hover', 
      content: 'Período: ' + info.event.groupId,
      container: 'body'
  });
  }

},
```

Notice in the first condition in the if statement for mobile the trigger is now set to click instead of hover. The idea is to set the event trigger properly. Again I have no idea about the thing you are using but the general idea is to set the trigger properly for mobile since hover really doesn't mean anything on a smart phone.

Comment: I tested the example you put here in the answer, but the result is the same. Whenever I click to see the tooltip it also opens the modal to edit the event

Comment: As I said, my example was only a shot in the dark to give you an idea of where to try, it wasn't meant to be a working solution. I have no way of producing a working solution when I don't actually know how everything works.